# Securing Stake Pool With Hardware Wallet

Tags: stake-pool, staking

was looking at this project for securing cardano stake pool node with a hardware wallet (trezor specifically) https://github.com/vacuumlabs/cardano-hw-cli

just curious if anyone out there has used this to secure their node, was it possible to use the "hidden" wallets feature in trezor?
also i'm curious if if all the signing and certs could be done with the trezor or do you still need a air-gapped environment for protecting keys? or is trezor the "airgapped" environment now?

Comment: I started my pool before using a hardware wallet for the cold key was possible, so I did not test this. But I don't see any reason why using the hidden wallet feature wouldn't work.
You still need an airgapped environment for enhanced security (the cold key is the most important key), but it is less important when you have the cold key on a hardware wallet.

Answer (score -1):

You do not secure your stake pool with your hardware wallet. What you are talking about is securing your pledge using your hardware wallet (with hidden wallet is ok). Then this hardware wallet is set as an owner on the stake pool.

Your airgapped stakepool keys are completely different. Those are used to set your pool information (margin, pledge, minFee, relays, metadata, etc..) and register owners. Those should remain airgapped for security.

Comment: You can also use the hardware wallet for the stake pool cold key. This is what the question is about. You cannot import the cold key of an existing stake pool in a hardware wallet, you need to create a new cold key (a new stake pool) for that.